# While populating spinner dataAdapter is shown null but it contains values

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to fetch some data into a spinner from database but it is showing the following error:-

```
07-21 05:54:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 05:54:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11918): Process: com.example.teste1, PID: 11918
07-21 05:54:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.teste1/com.example.teste1.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 05:54:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11918): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 05:54:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11918):    at com.example.teste1.MainActivity.loadSpinnerData(MainActivity.java:79)
07-21 05:54:42.450: E/AndroidRuntime(11918):    at com.example.teste1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
```

**line 79 is:-**  `spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`

**line 32 is:-** `loadSpinnerData();`

**I have checked if dataAdapter is null or not by using:-**

`System.out.println(dataAdapter.getItem(5).toString());`

*But it shows the value at 5th index, that means dataAdapter is not null.*

**This is my MainActivity class:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    Button btnDisplay;
    ImageButton btnAdd;
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnAdd = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        // Loading spinner data from database
        try {
            loadSpinnerData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        MyLayoutOperation.add(this, btnAdd);
        MyLayoutOperation.display(this, btnDisplay);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

 /**
 * Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database
 * @throws IOException 
 * */
    private void loadSpinnerData() throws IOException {

        // database handler
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());


        // Spinner Drop down elements
       List<String> products = db.getAllProducts();

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, products);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //For testing purpose only
        System.out.println(dataAdapter.getItem(5).toString());

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: are you sure `spinner` is not null?

Comment: I have checked the dataAdapter, it contains value

Comment: Do a Sysout on spinner, just before line 79

Comment: clean ur project then run it.

Comment: Is your spinner null? spinner1 id is inside activity_main.xml?

Comment: @Alexandre Santos checked by ` System.out.println(dataAdapter.getItem(5).toString());`   It prints the value

Comment: yes your `dataAdapter` is not `null` its `spinner` that is `null`.

Comment: `spinner` is not `dataAdapter`

Comment: Sorry guys. It was all due to a silly mistake. I forgot to put spinner in activity_main.xml. Thanks Pr38y for pointing it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spinner seems to be null. Try two things:-

1) Check if you have really created a `spinner` with id `spinner1` or not.
2) If you have created the spinner then try to check the values in it by doing Sysout on it.

Comment: Your first point is correct I forgot to design the spinner in my layout. Thanks for your time.